# How to display "This many months ago" in Django using Humanize?

Tags: python, django

I have this variable:

```
{{ video.pub_date }}
```

which outputs:

```
May 16, 2011, 2:03 p.m.
```

How can I get it to show:

```
1 month ago
```

I have loaded humanize on the page, but the django docs for humanize doesn't really show how to implement it to show what I want:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/

It just says that it's possible at the bottom of the page there.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to have the development version of Django to use the [**naturaltime** filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime)

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ video.pub_date|naturaltime }}
```

Humanize isn't a template tag, it's a library of [template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) which means when you load it you have access to various other filters included in the module.

Alternatively you can use the [**timesince** filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timesince) withouth having to load any other template tag libraries

```
{{ video.pub_date|timesince }}
```

Comment: timesince/ timeuntil filters are perfect :)

Comment: You can also use it with a production version of Django, not only the development version.

Comment: @kingmilo, thanks for mentioning timeuntil.

Answer (score 8):

```
{{ video.pub_date|timesince }} ago
```

From the docs at [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince)

> timesince
>
> Formats a date as the time since that
>   date (e.g., "4 days, 6 hours").
>
> Takes an optional argument that is a
>   variable containing the date to use as
>   the comparison point (without the
>   argument, the comparison point is
>   now). For example, if blog_date is a
>   date instance representing midnight on
>   1 June 2006, and comment_date is a
>   date instance for 08:00 on 1 June
>   2006, then {{
>   blog_date|timesince:comment_date }}
>   would return "8 hours".
>
> Comparing offset-naive and
>   offset-aware datetimes will return an
>   empty string.
>
> Minutes is the smallest unit used, and
>   "0 minutes" will be returned for any
>   date that is in the future relative to
>   the comparison point.

Answer (score 2):

To activate what filter. adds 'django.contrib.humanize' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting,

Once you’ve done that,

use `{% load humanize %}` in a templates, and you’ll have access to the follow filters,

{{comment.timestamp | naturaltime }}